# ListView sizes bigger than Window

Tags: c#, wpf

I am filling a ListView in my WPF Application through a webserver.
Once the Data is loaded, the ListView exeeds the bounds of its parent container and scales to infinity and Scrolling is no longer possible.

I already tried to set the MaxHeigth to the parents ActualHeight, which does not return the expected result.

```
<TabItem x:Name="unassingedErrors" Header="{x:Static p:Resources.MainContentPageUnassingedErrors}">
            <StackPanel>
                <Separator Grid.Row="1"/>
                <!--<Frame Grid.Row="2" Name="MainFrameError" Source="UnassignedErrorPage.xaml" />-->
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.DataContext>
                        <vme:UnassignedErrorPageVM x:Name="ViewModel"/>
                    </Grid.DataContext>
                    <ScrollViewer>
                        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding errorList}">
                            <ListView.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <ItemsPresenter></ItemsPresenter>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </ListView.Template>
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="{x:Static p:Resources.ErrorPageID}"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content="{x:Static p:Resources.ErrorPageText}"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Content="{x:Static p:Resources.ErrorPageThrowDate}"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Content="{x:Static p:Resources.ErrorPageHandledDate}"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Content="{x:Static p:Resources.ErrorPageIncident}"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" Content="{x:Static p:Resources.ErrorPageType}"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="6" Content="{x:Static p:Resources.ErrorPageSensor}"/>

                                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding ID}"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Text}"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Content="{Binding ThrowDate}"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Content="{Binding HandledDate}"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" Content="{Binding Incident.IncidentID}"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="5" Content="{Binding Type.Name}"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="6" Content="{Binding Sensor.Name}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem>
```

Comment: It seems to me, you shouldn't put your ListView in a <ScrollViewer>. Please try to remove ScrollViewer and when you have <ListView> under <Grid>.

Comment: ListView has its own ScrollViewer. You don´t havt to set a ScrollViewer around your ListView. Just remove it and it should work.

Comment: @StasIvanov, I tried It and it didn't change anything.

Comment: @Raphnika then you can try to define Height of the grid row containing the ListView as "*".

Comment: @StasIvanov sorry, but it still does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual problem is, that the scrollviewer does not know how high it should render itself, so it will not show the scrollbar.

My approach is to set the height of the scrollviewer with a binding to a height that you know very well. So I have put your code into a test window and gave it a name

```xml
<Window x:Class="MyTest.MainWindow" x:Name="myWindow" >

...

<ScrollViewer Height="{Binding ElementName=myWindow, Path=Content.ActualHeight}"  >
...
```

You can also use some other FrameworkElement of your choice to get the height from.

Comment: This answer helped big time. But when I am using the Window as a reference, the ScrollViewer is still a bit bigger thant it should be, since before and after the the TabControl containing the ScrollViewer are other controls.

Comment: You can also set your tab as source, or you can use a converter to reduce the size to the wanted one.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same markup and you should set MaxHeight property for ScrollViewer control. So this is my markup:

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" ScrollChanged="ScrollViewer_ScrollChanged" MaxHeight="100">
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="0" />
                        </Style>
                    </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Log" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Text}">
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

And this is how it looks like:
[image: Control view]

Comment: So this works, but I dont want to have a fixed number as the MaxHeight.

Comment: The main thing is that it should be set and should be less than Window height)